# How can I group specific 'months' from a vector and classify them as a chosen season in R?

Tags: r, data-extraction

So I'm new to R as I have to use it for a research project on chickens. My facilitator has said to look to see if the months/seasons cause any confounding in our data, but hasn't said how other than showed us how to take our column of dates and make it into a vector of months:

[image]

How can I take out specific months from the month_placed vector (e.g. 01,10,11,12) and classify them as a season e.g. winter?

Many thanks for any suggestions or simpler ways to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work. df stands for your dataframe:

`df$season[df$month_placed == 01 | df$month_placed == 10 | df$month_placed == 11 | df$month_placed == 12,] <- "winter"`

This is making a new column in your dataframe called 'season' and specifying that 'season' should be 'winter' when the month_placed was 01, 10, 11, or 12.

Let us know if you need clarification. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for answering :) when i copy the code in, it comes up with an error "Error in `*tmp*`$season : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" - I understand that this is a common error in R, but I'm such a rookie that I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you replaced every instance of 'df' in the code I have posted with the name of your dataframe? The 'df' I had there is just a common placeholder that means dataframe. If it is not the name of your dataframe, you will have to modify the code.